# React & TypeScript HOCs - why I get Type '{}' is not assignable to Type P?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-props, higher-order-components

I hit the wall while coding along with Learning React with TypeScript book. I surrendered and copy pasted code directly from the book, but compiler is still unhappy

My current workaround is to provide 'any' value, instead of IProps, but this is a cheap hack.

Not working code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IProps {
  loading: boolean;
}

const withLoader = <P extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FunctionComponent<P & IProps> => ({ loading, ...props }: 
IProps) =>
  loading ? (
    <div className="loader-overlay">
      <div className="loader-circle-wrap">
        <div className="loader-circle" />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Component {...props} />
  );

 export default withLoader;
```

Working code (I only changed IProps to any):

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IProps {
  loading: boolean;
}

const withLoader = <P extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FunctionComponent<P & IProps> => ({ loading, ...props }: 
any) =>
  loading ? (
    <div className="loader-overlay">
      <div className="loader-circle-wrap">
        <div className="loader-circle" />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Component {...props} />
  );

 export default withLoader;
```

In not working code, I get Type '{}' is not assignable to Type P error. I would like to solve this issue, as it would help me understand what is going on. I am total beginner at TypeScript!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with 3.2 the [behaviour of the spread operator for generics has changed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/11/29/announcing-typescript-3-2/#object-spread-on-generic-types). Apparently the type of `props` gets erased as a negative side effect, but you can work around that by casting it back to `P` using `{...props as P}` when spreading back into the wrapped component.